# VPN connection issues

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to create a VPN server so I can able to connect remotely plus able to access client computer data(Warehouse data ). However, I have done every requirement according to this tutorial videos( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qbpxKRb-94).

It remains unconnected to my client computer, i already did several research and possible solution but the outcome are either different errors or just blatanly doesnt work . I dont know what is the problem with this error (picture below). And still, i pinged both computer and it does recieved .

My server OS is a Window Server 2019

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Zi1.png)

Update:
Here is the configuration that I'm currently have
I'm using Routing and Remote Access to create a VPN server . However, I did allow routing on Windows firewall and configure port forwarding to 1723 on my router.
Although, the VPN server is being joined among with other services such as DNS,DHCP and DC
As for the VPN configuration, i did set type of VPN to Automatic along with data encryption to Optional encryption .Plus'checking for Allow these protocols

Comment: Let's start with "what are the errors you're getting"?

Comment: @music2myear The error that im currently having is " The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might not be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an L2P/IPsec tunnel,the security paramenter required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured " . Its in the post in which i already linked.

Comment: Which VPN type did you use? L2TP or PPTP? Please change VPN type to automatic or PPTP to do a test, check if you could connect to VPN. If it still doesn't work, disable both firewall on client side and server side, then check the result again.

Comment: @Candy I'm currently using PPTP and I have applied your testing and the result is a different error for PPTP . The error said that  "the network connection between your computer and the VPN server was interrupted . This can be caused by a problem in the VPN transmission and commonly the result of internet latency or simply that your VPN server has reached capacity"

Comment: Please first check if VPN client can ping VPN server. Also disable firewall on both client side and server side. Verify that your VPN IP address, username, and password are all correct.

Comment: All of this information we're having to ask questions to get needs to be in the question. Please use the EDIT button to add it to make your question a better, more clear, more complete question.

Comment: @music2myear Hey there, I have already updated information regarding to my configuration. I dont know if it is enough but please let me know

Comment: @Candy I have ping both machine and all of them respond normally. As for the user, i did enter the correct user and password